# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer rollup@"^1.20.0||^2.0.0" from @rollup/plugin-commonjs@11.1.0

Tags: npm, installation, rollup

I am getting error while installing the latest version (25.0.7)-

```
npm i @rollup/plugin-commonjs or
npm i @rollup/plugin-commonjs@25.0.7


npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rollup@4.9.4
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup
npm ERR!   dev rollup@"^4.9.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rollup@"^1.20.0||^2.0.0" from @rollup/plugin-commonjs@11.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@rollup/plugin-commonjs
npm ERR!   dev @rollup/plugin-commonjs@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

I am having `rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^11.1.0"` in my package.json.

Can anyone please help me ?
Thank you

installing the latest version of rollup/plugin-commonjs(25.0.7)